# SSRS count if > 0 Expression

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008, countif

I'm trying to build a report but am stuck on an expression that feels simple but I can't figure out. I've been going through different possible solutions but nothing has worked. What I need is the following:

I have a database that holds transport orders, some of these transport orders match with others.  My goal is to show, per customer, on one side a count the total amount of transport orders (By postID) and on the same row the count (By postID) of orders where the "Matchcount" > 0.

I managed to show total count of orders and total sum of matches.

I tried the following formula but that did not work. Please Help!!

`=count(IIf(Fields!Sum_Potential_Match_Count.Value > 0, Fields!PostStatusID.Value,0))`

View on how the report should be built:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count` simply counts the rows that are returned.  As far as I am aware you can't filter as you are trying to do.

Instead, you can use `=sum(iif(Fields!Sum_Potential_Match_Count.Value > 0, 1,0))`

---

Oh do you want to sum up the values in Sum_Potential_Match_Count?  In that case you can just `sum` on the field?

`=sum(Fields!Sum_Potential_Match_Count.Value)`

Comment: This expression just gives 1 or 0 as a result.

Comment: @mdeheus90  Does your dataset only have one row in it with a Sum_Potential_Match_Count that is greater than 0?  This expression will look at every value in that column and `sum` up the 1 or 0 that results from the `iif`.  If you have 10 rows = 0 and 20 rows = 5, a `count` will return 30 and my expression will return 20.

Comment: @mdeheus90  I have also edited my answer to simply sum up the values in your `Sum_Potential_Match_Count` column.

Comment: thanks for all the responses. What i need to get out of it is the following. Column 1: total count of transport orders, Column 2: total count of transport orders with potential matches, Column 3: total sum of potential matches. Columns 1 and 3 are no problem. i have these results only column 2 is a problem.

Comment: @mdeheus90  How you do that depends entirely on what is being returned in your dataset, which you have not included in your question.  Please add the raw output of your query to your question.

Comment: that was just the comment I needed. The build of the query was not good. changing the aggregates made the formula work. That makes the problem solved. Thanks for helping out.